# Solving the clothing problem with Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, differential-geometry

Given a surface $\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, the Chebyshev clothing problem consists in finding a parametrization $(u,v)$ such that

\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u} \right|^2=\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v} \right|^2=1,
\end{align}

so that $u$ and $v-$ constant lines on the surface can be viewed as warp and weft. If $\mathbf{r}$ is given as a funtion $\mathbf{r}(\xi,\eta)$ then the problem can be stated a system of PDEs for $\xi(u,v)$ and $\eta(u,v)$. This differential approach is not convenient when the surface is not easily parametrizable, and there are a few methods, like the [compass method](https://rynne.es/projects/2017-12-chebyshevnet), that take a discrete surface and construct the Chebyshev net up to some accuracy. I wonder if some work along these lines exists with Mathematica.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific problem surface in mind? Can you share a concrete example in code? Otherwise your question may end up closed as either too broad or lacking valid code.